# Show that $\mathcal{B}^s$ is the smallest $\sigma$-field

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the Borel $\sigma$-field on $\mathbb{R}$. We denote the reflection of a set B to be $B^-:=\{x\in \mathbb{R}: -x\in B\}$. Let $\mathcal{B}^s$ be the collection of symmetric Borel sets, i.e., $ \mathcal{B}^s:=\{B\cup B^-: B\in \mathcal{B}\}$.

Show that $\mathcal{B}^s$ is the smallest $\sigma$-field to make all continuous even functions from $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}^s)\to (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$ be measurable.

---

My idea is that

(1) I first try to show that $\mathcal{B}^s$ is a $\sigma$-field. But I am stuck on the second point that for any $A\in \mathcal{B}^s$, the complement $A^c$ is also in $\mathcal{B}^s$. Since $A\in \mathcal{B}^s$, then $A=B\cup B^-$. Then $A^c=B^c\cap (B^-)^c$. How to rewrite it as the union of two Borel sets?

For the countable union, it is trivial. For $\{A_i\}_i\subset \mathcal{B}^s$, $\cup_i A_i=\cup_i (B_i\cup B_i^-)\in \mathcal{B}^s$ because $\cup_i B_i\in \mathcal{B}$ and $\cup_i B_i^-\in \mathcal{B}$.

(2) I am stuck on how to show that $\mathcal{B}^s$ is the smallest one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\mathcal{B}^s$ is simply the collection of all symmetric Borel sets, i.e:

$\mathcal{B}^s=\{B\in\mathcal{B}: x\in B \iff -x\in B\}$

Indeed, if $B$ is any Borel set then clearly $B\cup B^-$ is a symmetric Borel set. Conversely, if $C$ is a symmetric Borel set then $C=C^-$, and so $C=C\cup C^-\in\mathcal{B}^s$. So now what you basically have to show is that the set $A^c=B^c\cap (B^-)^c$ is both Borel and symmetric. This is almost trivial, so I'll leave it to you.

As for the second part, first note that any continuous even function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is indeed measurable with respect to $\mathcal{B}^s$. Now let $\mathcal{F}$ be the smallest sigma-field on $\mathbb{R}$ with this property. We want to show that $\mathcal{B}^s=\mathcal{F}$. We know that $\mathcal{F}\subseteq\mathcal{B}^s$, so in particular all sets in $\mathcal{F}$ are symmetric. We have to show the other inclusion. For this, first show that for any $a>0$ we have $(-a,a)\in\mathcal{F}$, this is easy. And now define:

$\mathcal{F}_+=\{A\in\mathcal{B}([0,\infty)): A\cup A^-\in\mathcal{F}\}$

This is a $\sigma$-field on $[0,\infty)$. (the only tricky part is showing closure under complement. Try to use the fact that any set in $\mathcal{F}$ is symmetric) Since every set of the form $[0,a)$ belongs to $\mathcal{F}_+$ (as we already showed), and sets of such form generate $\mathcal{B}([0,\infty))$, it follows that $\mathcal{F}_+=\mathcal{B}([0,\infty))$. This means that for any $A\in\mathcal{B}([0,\infty))$ we have $A\cup A^-\in\mathcal{F}$. But finally, note that any set of $\mathcal{B}^s$ is of this form. So indeed we proved that $\mathcal{B}^s\subseteq\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: Thank you! How to show that any continuous even function $f: R\to R$ is indeed measurable with respect to $\mathcal{B}^s$?

Comment: @Hermi It's sufficient to show that the inverse image of any open set belongs to $\mathcal{B}^s$. Well, if the function is continuous and even, what can you say about $f^{-1}(U)$ when $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is open?

Comment: Yes, I know that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open. But where do we use the fact that $f$ is even?

Comment: @Hermi In order to belong to $\mathcal{B}^s$, the set $f^{-1}(U)$ has to be not just Borel, but also symmetric. This happens because $f$ is even. If $x\in f^{-1}(U)$ then $f(-x)=f(x)\in U$, and so $-x\in f^{-1}(U)$ as well.